# In Delphi, I can use a destroyed object without an error! Is it possible?

Tags: delphi, oop, free

I am trying to use a thread for a web service call. For this reason I defined a simple object and called its method from a thread.

But I realized that after destroying that object I can still use its method without any error and it returns the correct answer. How can it be possible? Do you have any comment?

```
// TThreadMethod is defined in Classes.pas 

TThreadMethod = procedure of object;


*********************
      Interface 
*********************

TMyObject = class(TObject)
  procedure DoSomething;
end;

TMyThread = class(TThread)
private
  FMethod : TThreadMethod;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create(aMethod: TThreadMethod);
end;

*********************
   Implementation 
*********************

// I called the thread and destroyed the object immediately. 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aObject : TMyObject;
begin
  aObject := TMyObject.Create;
  TMyThread.Create(aObject.DoSomething);
  FreeAndNil(aObject); // Object itself was destroyed here.
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(aMethod: TThreadMethod);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FMethod := aMethod;
  Resume;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  Sleep(10000); // wait 10 sec. before calling the method
  // The object was already destroyed but it doesn't produce any error!
  FMethod; // It calls the web service method and returns correct result. But how???     
end;

procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
begin
  // Call a web service method and show the result on the form.
end;
```

Comment: To a certain extent, yes this is possible. But of course is not recommended. Methods of an object can work, so long as there are no fields such as strings, integers, or anything else that requires memory allocation. If inside this function you have for example `FSomeString := 'Some Value';` it would fail, assuming this string is inside the object. But it can however do work with data outside the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Delphi objects assigned even after calling .Free?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235033/why-are-delphi-objects-assigned-even-after-calling-free)

Comment: No, this is different than that question. In that question, the question is related nil assignment of pointer. In my case, I destroyed the object itself but its method is still working. They are completely different.

Comment: Related: [What's supposed to happen when using an object after FreeAndNil?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/364231/33732)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is not tied to the object, but to the class ...

```
type
TMyObject = class(TObject)
 published
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
TSomeProcedure=Procedure of object;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  .....
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation    
{$R *.dfm}    
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 p:TSomeProcedure;
 M:TMethod;
begin
 m.Code := TMyObject.MethodAddress('DoSomething');
 m.Data := nil;
 p := TSomeProcedure(m);
 p;
end;

procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
begin
  Showmessage('Hallo');
end;
```

EDIT an additional example would be

```
type
TMyObject = class(TObject)
 published
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
begin
  Showmessage('Hallo');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 o1,o2:TMyObject;
begin
 o1:=TMyObject.Create;
 o2:=TMyObject.Create;
 Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(Integer(TMyObject.MethodAddress('DoSomething')),4));
 Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(Integer(o1.MethodAddress('DoSomething')),4));
 Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(Integer(o2.MethodAddress('DoSomething')),4));
 o1.Free;
 o2.Free;
end;
```

Comment: It's very interesting! I didn't know it. Thanks for the examples.

Comment: @JackHouston notice that those methods are static. Virtual/dynamic/message methods would not work this exotic way. If you truly need somethign like this - read about `class methods`.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Using any type of non-class method on a destroyed instance does necessarily trigger any exceptions. If the memory has not been overwritten yet, or the methods do not use any instance variables, execution can succeed and you are in for a nice debugging session when it does start failing. "It used to work, why does it suddenly throw an exception", or even: "It works here, but fails from another thread, or three loop iterations later."

Comment: @MarjanVenema no, no. Not for *static* procedures. Their address is known before the address of instance is set, and compiler puts their address directly into code! http://pastebin.ca/2385825  This code does make NO ANY access to the instance, thus no AV happens.  I agree this is a road to hell in general, but it works in this strict conditions.

Comment: @Arioch'The: You actually can do that for virtual/dynamic/message methods just as well. Their address is tied to the class, not the instance, exactly as bummi is saying. The address of those types of method is also know before the address of the instance is known. The only difference is for non-static methods `MethodAddress`has to go through the VMT. Whether you call any method of a class on an instance (`SomeObject.SomeProcedure`) or use bummi's "trick" through a `TMethod` variable doens't make any difference. ... continued...

Comment: @Arioch'The ... And any method, regardless of how it is called, can bomb out with an AV when you pass it a nil or invalid pointer for its `Self` parameter and the method's implementation does use instance data.

Comment: @MarjanVenema *The only difference is for non-static methods MethodAddresshas to go through the VMT* Good guess. And to get the address of the VMT you should ask the INSTANCE for the VMT address. Thus every v/d/m method DOES USE instance data just by the fact it was called. *and the method's implementation does use instance data* and this assumption violates prerequisite that was implicitly stated  above and explicitly stated in aforementioned http://pastebin.ca/2385825

Comment: @Arioch'The: That may be one way, but not the only one. I am no VMT expert, but I am pretty sure any class's VMT information is accessible without having to construct an instance of that class first. RTTI (especially extended RTTI) wouldn't be able to work without it.

Comment: *any class's VMT information* - sure! but you DO NOT KNOW the class, that is THE ESSENSE of v-methods. `var i: TIniFile` - which class is ? Is it TIniFile or TMemIniFile or TRegIniFile or TSQLIniFile ? `var f: TCustomForm` - what the class is it? Is it `TForm1` or `TForm2` or `TForm3` ?  Plz, @MarjanVenema, do tell me this, with 100% accuracy (as compiler should do) and w/o accessing the instance (as we agreed upon not touching the instance/Self). So, tell me the exact class behind those variables so we could choose matching VMT and do the call, w/o actually reading the pointer. Please?

Comment: @Arioch'The [example soure](http://bummisoft.de/download/DEMO_MethodCalls.zip) . An object knows it's class and is able to make call the according calls (better the compiler knows) but the calls are not tied to an object. (we agree about instance and self)

Comment: @bummi why not just publish it on WWW, rather than hop through download, unzip... Okay, `o1.MethodAddress` looking at .MethodAddress implementation we see it's second line is `LSelf := Pointer(Self);`

Comment: Okay, let's wrap it up like this: 1) at the moment of calling, either instance should exists or method should not use instance-related data. 2) at the moment of obtaining and latching the pointer to method, either the method should be static or the instance should exist. 3) usually obtaining address is made right before the call, but sometimes ( for example using procedure pointers or closures ) this can be separated in time.

Comment: Thanks bummi for stepping in. I was going to make a similar example project, just hadn't found the time yet.